# to excel pivot table in tabular view/repeat items

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I would like to send to excel a pivot table done with python/pandas in a tabular view repeating in each line the item values:

Thank you for your help!

Here the code:

```
df2 = pd.pivot_table(dataframe,index= 
['COD_ARTC','COD_COLR','START_CONF_WEEK', 'START_REQ_WEEK'],values = 
'QTY_ORDERED',aggfunc=np.sum)
writer_orig = pd.ExcelWriter('test2.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df2.to_excel(writer_orig, index=True)
writer_orig.save()
```

Output in the file 'test2.xlsx':

```
COD_ARTC COD_COLR START_CONF_WEEK START_REQ_WEEK    QTY_ORDERED
SKU41-51 black  201852            201852              15
        201903            201851              6
                      201903              33
```

But I would like to have this:

```
COD_ARTC  COD_COLR START_CONF_WEEK  START_REQ_WEEK  QTY_ORDERED
SKU41-51 black     201852   201852                  15
SKU41-51 black     201903   201851                  6
SKU41-51 black     201903   201903                   33
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: did you mean using `df2.ffill()` ?

Answer (score 0):

if I add merge_cells=False in to_ excel, it works

df2.to_excel(writer_orig, index=True, merge_cells=False)